# error al installar JSPM (node JS)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, aplicación-web

intento instalar JSPM con estos comandos
http://jspm.io/docs/getting-started.html
pero tengo un error al intentarlo pruebo con  el comando
    **npm install jspm -g** y obtengo un error **Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher** pero reviso la version del minimatch y es la **3.10.7***
no entiendo tengo **NODE v6.5.0**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

`JSPM` están probablemente relacionados con la versión de `Node.JS` en su sistema. Su V6  que ejecuta, trate de cambiar a V5 no todos los paquetes están listos aún para V6 y se ve como JSPM tiene algunos problemas con el V6.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba instalando esa version : 
 `npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2`

Answer (score 1):

JSPM v0.16 probablemente tiene una dependencia a minimatch^2. Eso es independiente de la versión que tengas en tu sistema.

Eso que te está saliendo es un warning, no un error. Efectivamente minimatch 2 tiene defectos que ameritan recomendar su upgrade, pero tu instalación de jspm debiese haberse completado igual.